# Can re-factoring of HTML 4 into HTML5 increase the performance of website?

Tags: performance, html

Can using HTML5 things increase the speed and performance of website?

Or it will only increase the semanticists and add new technology and user experience.

Answer (score 3):

HTML 5 adds some new controls that browsers can implement natively (like calenders). Using these will improve performance over JavaScript implemented controls (but in general, you will not notice much difference).

Answer (score 1):

No doubt a lot of new elements are introduced in HTML5, but that should not have any direct considerable effect on the overall speed or performance of the website. In HTML5, Strict parsing and lexing rules are introduced to handle any errors, and the introduction of multimedia elements, `<audio>`, `<video>` (that wouldn't require support from third party software), the performance or the threshold efficiency is indirectly improved.

Answer (score 1):

Well there is not a lot in HTML 5 to make things faster directly other than the new elements mentioned and maybe local storage.   In stead the reality is that most HTML 5 supporting browsers are faster, some significantly.   So by going to HTML 5 and forcing a user upgrade your your client part of an app should be faster.

For example look into the bleeding edge browsers acceleration via GPUs and better multiple threading.  So your client might be faster by default simply because you would end up executing on a better browser.  Combined with new features in HTML you may bel able to speed up Your pages.